# Clear Autocomplete Data Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

[image]

You can see above image, if I select Recipient Organization, Recipient autocomplete box shows all recipients of the selected organization. But the problem is if the organization has not any recipients, autocomplete box shows previous recipients. that should not be. I want to clear previous autocomplete data list on the **onChange of Organization drop down**. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make the source empty

Try like this

```
// suppose your autocomplete selector is id='image'
$("#image").autocomplete({"source": [""]});
```

or you can destory it

like this

```
$("#image").autocomplete("destroy");
```

Then re-assing data to autocomplete onchange

like this

```
$("#image").autocomplete({"source": datasrouce});
```

Comment: $("#image").autocomplete({"source": [""]}). Perfectly worked. thanks!! I was using single quotes '' instead [""], and single quote was making request to Server on the onKeyDown  event of autocomplete box, that was the problem. now it's fixed thanks